# How to build a textual search engine?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am having an HTML string and want to find out if a word I supply is relevant in that string.

Relevancy could be measured based on frequency in the text.

An example to illustrate my problem:

```
this is an awesome bike store
bikes can be purchased online.
the bikes we own rock.
check out our bike store now
```

Now I want to test a few other words:

```
bike repairs
dog poo
```

`bike repairs` should be marked as relevant whereas `dog poo` should not be marked as relevant.

Questions:

- How could this be done?
- How to I filter out ambiguous words like `in` or `or`

Thanks for your ideas!

I guess it's something Google does to figure out what keywords are relevant to a website. I am basically trying to reproduce their on-page rankings.

Comment: Huge topic, have a look at [Into to IR](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/), this walks you from basic first principles how to build what you are asking about. Something to lookup is [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) then realise this doesn't solve everything and look at bayesian probability

Comment: Why do you consider "repairs" as relevant?

Comment: Was just an example. Didn't think too much about it :). I guess it is not relevant?

Comment: @Hendrik: please, use @<username> to address user - SE didn't notify me about your comment. Counting relevancy is the key point in search engines (though normally you compute how relevant is web page to a search query, you need it, right?). Do I understand it right that you just want to know how to compute relevancy of document to a search query when there are similar, but not exact words (e.g. "bike" and, say, "cyclist")?

Comment: I guess you are asking for two things. One is a rather well understood search problem. You can just use Solr or Elasticsearch to do the heavy lifting for you. They both can find relevant documnents in a collection by weighting hits. However if you want some deeper semantic understanding of the text (i.e. "repair" is not mentioned but a typical activity in a bike shop) then the pure search engine might fall flat.

Answer (score 4):

- pre-process your documents (some of the steps may be skipped)

  - [tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization)
  - [remove stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)
  - [stem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) or [lemmatize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)
  - do normalization (e.g. U.S.A. -> USA, météo -> meteo, etc) and orthographic correction
  - perform phonetic normalization (e.g. with [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex))
  - find equivalence classes (using thesauri, e.g. [WordNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet))
- use a [Vector Space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) to represent documents (you may use TF, aforementioned [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) or other models)
- do the same with the query: preprocess and represent it in the vector space
- find the most similar documents by computing the vector similarity (e.g. using the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity))

That's an outline of the [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) process

[Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) by Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze is a very good book to get started in IR.

---

Or just use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to get everything you need out of the box (or [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), that is used by Solr, to build your own application)

Answer (score 1):

I remember a long time ago playing with Elastic Search (the website is very different now from what I remember). There is some stuff about dealing with human language [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/languages.html).

Be warned that Elastic search is like a big bazooka to your problem. If your problem is very simple, maybe you want to go from scratch. There is some docs in the web about it.